# Extjs domQuery using grid.up().query()

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am facing problem in using the domquery, to get focus on the control previous to grid when the grid cell is in edit mode, What i am trying is

1.check the grid tabindex add 1 to it, gridTabIndex = grid.dom.tabindex - 1

2.do grid.up() to look out for main form ,

3.then search using **domquery form.query('input[tabindex = gridTabIndex]')** for the field with the tabindex  = grid.tabindex - 1

using grid.up().query() gives the below output as shown in image

[image: Output of grid.up().query()]

So the point 3 is where i am facing problem. it gives an empty array // output is []

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.query` **doesn't** query Dom Elements. It queries ExtJs Components. However `form.getEl().query` **do** query for Dom Elements. Give it a try. (Notice, [Ext.dom.Element.query](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-query) is available only since 4.1.0)